# Would pressure decrease if I added a tesla turbine to the pipe system?

Tags: energy, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, bernoulli-equation

There's constant 2 psi of gas in my pipes. Once I open the valve the gas begins to spew out. Would psi decrease if I added a few tesla turbines connected to a generator in the pipe system? I added a photo example.

Gas tank > Constant 2psi gas in pipe > turbine > [image]

Answer (score 0):

[Bernoulli's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle)  law says that pressure will decrease with an increase of the flow speed.

Turbines will lower the speed therefore pressure in the pipe will increase further adding turbines.